# Pivot table with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like:

```
Region|Value|Driver|
GR    |1    |capex
GR    |2    |opex
```

What I need to do is have both drivers as as columns like:

```
Region|Capex|Opex
GR    |1    |2
```

I know how to unpivot but pivoting is giving me a problem as there are two columns.
Any idea how I can achieve this? By the way there's  more than one `Driver` but i only need the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use *conditional* aggregation :

```
select Region,
       sum(case when Driver = 'capex' then Value else 0 end) Capex,
       sum(case when Driver = 'opex' then Value else 0 end) opex
from table t
where Driver in ('capex', 'opex')
group by Region;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one column you need to pivot (`driver`) with the values of `Value`.

```
SELECT
    P.Region,
    P.capex,
    P.opex
FROM
    YourTable AS T
    PIVOT (
        MAX(T.Value) FOR T.Driver IN ([capex], [opex])
    ) AS P
```

Please review if you need a `MAX()` (or `SUM()`, etc.).

Comment: the error im receiving says invalid column name 'capex'

Comment: I can't find any syntax error. Please post your table definition.